# uncaught exception: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

all. I have built a simple jQuery/PHP chat program that works rather well. However, I'd like to add a feature like channels or rooms. Ideally, I'd like to use tabs at the top of the chat to manage which room the user is in (there are only going to be 2). I thought this would be a simple task, and I have seen something similar done before, but I keep getting the uncaught exception error when the tabs are clicked, and the source doesn't load correctly. i'll post the code for the whole chat system, because I have a feeling the issue might lie therein.

the jquery

```
page = {
    getChat: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'game_src.php',
            data: 'mode=getChat',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function(res){
                $("#chatbox").html(res);
            }
        });
    }
};

$("#submitmsg").click(function(){
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'game_src.php',
        data: 'mode=chatSubmit&msg=' + encodeURIComponent(clientmsg)
    });
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
    return false;
});

setInterval(page.getChat, 4000);

$("#chatChannel").tabs({
    cookie: { expires: 1 },
});
```

the chat body

```
<?php
if($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)
{

}
else
{
    ?>
    <div id="chatChannel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#global">Global</a></li>
            <li><a href="#alli">Alliance</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <form name="message" action="">  
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="25" />  
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send" />  
    </form>
    <br />
    <?php
}
?>
<div id="chatbox" style="border:1px solid black;background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);height:400px;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="global">
    <?php
    $chatMsgs = array();
    $limit = time()-86400;

    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(chat_id) as count FROM '.CHAT_TABLE.' WHERE chat_channel = 0 AND chat_time > '.$limit;
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
    $count = $row['count'];

    if($count > 0)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.CHAT_TABLE.' WHERE chat_channel = 0 AND chat_time > '.$limit.' ORDER BY chat_time DESC';
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
        while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
        {
            $chatMsgs[] = array(
                'chat_time' => $row['chat_time'],
                'chat_msg' => $row['chat_msg'],
                'chat_user' => $row['chat_user'],
                'chat_channel' => $row['chat_channel']
            );
        }

        foreach($chatMsgs as $msg)
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT username FROM '.USERS_TABLE.' WHERE user_id = '.$msg['chat_user'];
            $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
            $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
            $username = $row['username'];

            echo '<div class="chatMsg" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">';
            echo '<div class="chatUsr">'.$username.' says:</div>';
            echo '<div class="chatUsrMsg" style="float:left;">'.$msg['chat_msg'].'</div>';
            echo '<div class="chatMsgTime" style="float:right;">'.date("g:i a", $msg['chat_time']).'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<br />';
            echo '<hr />';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="chatMsg">Nothing is heard but the sound of crickets...</div>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="alli">
    <?php
    $chatMsgs = array();
    $limit = time()-86400;

    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(chat_id) as count FROM '.CHAT_TABLE.' WHERE chat_channel = 1 AND chat_time > '.$limit;
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
    $count = $row['count'];

    if($count > 0)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.CHAT_TABLE.' WHERE chat_channel = 1 AND chat_time > '.$limit.' ORDER BY chat_time DESC';
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
        while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
        {
            $chatMsgs[] = array(
                'chat_time' => $row['chat_time'],
                'chat_msg' => $row['chat_msg'],
                'chat_user' => $row['chat_user'],
                'chat_channel' => $row['chat_channel']
            );
        }

        foreach($chatMsgs as $msg)
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT username FROM '.USERS_TABLE.' WHERE user_id = '.$msg['chat_user'];
            $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
            $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
            $username = $row['username'];

            echo '<div class="chatMsg" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">';
            echo '<div class="chatUsr">'.$username.' says:</div>';
            echo '<div class="chatUsrMsg" style="float:left;">'.$msg['chat_msg'].'</div>';
            echo '<div class="chatMsgTime" style="float:right;">'.date("g:i a", $msg['chat_time']).'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<br />';
            echo '<hr />';
                    }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="chatMsg">Nothing is heard but the sound of crickets...</div>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm going to add a parameter to the getChat jquery function to switch back and forth, but with what i have, i'm stuck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The JQuery UI tabs plugin expects the content `div`s to be in the same container as the `ul` of links.

In your case, it expects the content `div`s to be in the `div id="chatChannel"` right under the `ul`, but they aren't there.

Comment: In my my code the div are rightly nested. where else could the problem be?

Answer (score -3):

I had this problem while implementing jquery UI tabs into a jQuery Mobile application. 
using

jquery 1.7.2

jquery UI 1.8.2

jQuery Mobile 1.1.

Aparentry the problem is compatibility versions between jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile versions.

After reading evry bug report and switching between library versions of jQuery, i found the solution downgrading to the jQuery Mobile Legacy version 1.0.1 which did not get in conflict with jQuery UI tabs component.

Hope that developers of jQuery Mobile fix this for future versions